# How to Compare the button frame in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop

I am developing an application where I am creating multiple buttons in UIView. Here, user is able to move the button location anywhere in the view, and whenever the button position is changed, I want to compare the moved button location frame with the previous frame. Let me explain briefly, if `( btn1 )` in the position of `(100, 100, 30,40)` and `( btn2 )` in the position of  `( 200,100,30,40)`, and  when I am dragging my `( btn1 )` to the new position, here I want to get the moved location frame and compare with the `( btn2 )` frame. If it equals then I would like to move `( btn2 )` to  `(btn1)` and `(btn1)` to `(btn2)`.

eg:

```
Btn1(100, 100, 30,40)                 Btn2 ( 200,100,30,40)
```

Comment: what have you tried?  frames are just 4 values, just need to compare all four to each other for equality.  if(x1==x2 && y1==y2 && w1==w2 && h1==h2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CGRectEqualToRect(<#CGRect rect1#>, <#CGRect rect2#>)`